# jquery if div empty display 2nd div else first

Tags: javascript, jquery

If `#ccs-inline` has content then I want to hide `#inpage` otherwise I want to show `#inpage`.
The issue I have is that if the first div has no content but second div does then it doesn't display the content of second div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#ccs-inline:not(:empty)')){
    $('#inpage').hide();
    } else {
        $('#inpage').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: How does your `html` look like ?

Comment: each div id is a  placement for iframe.. ..i am not sure what you mean by html look like

Comment: Sushanth is asking if you can post the relevant HTML

Comment: <div id="inpage"></div>
<div id="ccs-inline"></div>

Answer (score 3):

Use `.length`, to confirm there is no empty div. Since the jQuery returns a jQuery object hence your if condition will always be true.

Example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#ccs-inline:not(:empty)').length > 0) {
    $('#inpage').hide();
  } else {
    $('#inpage').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: i tried this earlier on.. if both div have content then it display both div.

Comment: @naf : Are you sure the this code gets executed after the content is loaded in the div's ?

Comment: i added this code in the footer .. after the remote  javascript for the other two div is  executed.

Comment: Could you place a debugger in if condition and make sure that the code is executed and only after the content of div is loaded.